# Count amount of words in a string without any loops

Tags: java

For example you send a string "Yo what’s up dog?" to a function, the function returns 4 counts.

below is what I wrote:

```
public class CountString {
    public int count(String str){
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0; i<str.length();i++){
            if(str.charAt(i) == ' ')
                count++;
        }
        System.out.printf("\n number of strings: "+ (count+1));
        return count+1;
    }
}
```

Are there any other faster methods? Now how do you perform the same job without including any loops (for, while, do-while)?

Comment: You can call other library methods that do it for you, but these methods contain loops. It's not possible to go over something that has an up-front unknown length without loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
String s = "Yo what’s up dog?";
String[] arr = s.split(" ");
System.out.println(arr.length); //prints 4
```

Comment: Thank you. I know it's off topic but is there a C++ equivalent of this method?

Answer (score 1):

Without loop! -

One way using `String#split`

1. split the string with `' '` (space)
2. get the Word count

Code snippet -

```
return str.trim().split(" ");
```

One other way is using `StringTokenizer` -

```
 StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str); // default delimiter is space
 return st.countTokens();
```